How to increase SSRS report timeout while rendering in report viewer
We are using Report Viewer to render the SSRS report. The SSRS report  takes around 5 minutes time to render report.
The report viewer stops processing after 1 minute of time.
We are using MVC views and in view we are rendering the
@Html.ReportViewer(Model)

I Have tried below code snippet, but still the report timesout after 1 minute.
        ssrsReportFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RptDir"].ToString();
        ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
        reportViewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
        reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServer_URL"].ToString());
        reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = String.Format("/{0}/{1}", ssrsReportFolder, ssrsReportName);
        reportViewer.SizeToReportContent = false;
        reportViewer.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);//reportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
        reportViewer.Height = Unit.Pixel(1000);
        reportViewer.ServerReport.Timeout = 1200000;
        reportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
        return View(MVCViews._ReportViewer, reportViewer);

Please let me know how can we increase time interval
